# Is it possible to prevent a WebBrowser control from being disposed due to a script which invokes window.close() on it?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, dispose

Is there any way to neutralize 'window.close()' calls? The closest I got was this:

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/05/21/Extended-WebBrowser-Control-Series-WebBrowser-Control-and-windowClose().aspx

However, by reading the article linked above I get the feeling that 'window.close()' seals the fate of the web browser control and that the only way for it's parent form to move on is to completely dispose of the web browser and replace it on the spot with a new one (as described in one of the links of the article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the link below and according to it one can indeed neutralize window.close() by means of DWebBrowserEvents2 interface (somehow I didnt manage to find this post when I was looking into the issue):

[WebBrowser and javascript window.close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535575/webbrowser-and-javascript-window-close)